# Custom scaffolding template location for .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, scaffolding

I want to customize the scaffolding template for .NET Core 3.1 . I am unable to find the location of scaffolding template for ASP.NET Core 3.1. I searched a lot but all searches ends up for .NET Core 2.1.

Further following location does not work for me,

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web\Mvc\Scaffolding\Templates 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web\MVC 4\CodeTemplates
C:\Users\<user>\.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.web.codegenerators.mvc\3.1.4\Templates
```

I changed the template in above locations but they are not reflecting whenever I create new item.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to custom scaffolding template in your project,you can do like this:

Firstly,copy the Templates folder to your project:
[image]

Then change the Tempaltes in the folder,and create scaffold item in the project,it will work.(In .net core,add a new template to it,it will not work,you can only modify the default templates by the way)

Here is a demo:

I changed the Create.cshtml in Templates/ViewGenerator(it's a .net core mvc project,so I deleted Identity,Identity_Versioned,RazorPageGenerator,RazorPageGenerator_Versioned folder):

[image]

I change

[image]

to

[image]

result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can see in

[image]

For example:

```
C:\Users\MyName\.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.web.codegenerators.mvc
```

If you need a programable way: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/creating-a-custom-scaffolder-for-visual-studio/

Comment: As I already mentioned that  I looked into this folder, but any change of template, exist in this folder is not reflecting while creating new template. Further given link is not applicable for visual studio 2019.